# Adding Time Intervals SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to add time entries from a table.  The time entries are stored as

P2H30M  (2 Hours 30 Minutes)

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding time intervals to other time intervals? Or time intervals to another column that's defined as a datetime?

Either way, you'd want to create a function to convert those values to an integer (minutes) and then add the integers together and use another function to convert them back to your proprietary character format.

If you're wanting to add them to a datetime column you could then use:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET YourDateTimeCol = DATEADD(MI, YourDateTimeCol, <yourminuteinteger>) 
WHERE <whatever your where clause would be>
```

Comment: The would need to be added together just as Sum() would do for integers.

Comment: All the same, if you made a function to convert that proprietary format to an integer and then SUM()'d that, and converted it back you'd achieve the same result. It would be awfully slow though, can you not just store them differently?